# Hiding and showing a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code that is generated by PHP.

```
<p id="resp19" class="resp">
<img src="logos/RO.png"><br>
<b>CompanyRO</b>
<span class="fprice">XXXXXX</span>
<span class="f_row">
<input name="first_row" type="radio">AAAAAAAAAA</span><br>
<span class="buts"><input class="f_det" value="Details" onclick="ShowDetails(resp19)" type="button">                                             
<input class="f_det" value="Share" type="button"></span>
<span style="display: none;" class="details_content">
Detalii
</span>
```

After this, I'm hidding this span `$('.details_content').hide();`.
I want that when I press the Details button, the span with details_content is shown, only for this `<p>`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you show your full jquery code.

Comment: i don't know how to write ShowDetails functions, where i pass the id of the current p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass string to function `onclick="ShowDetails(resp19)"`:

```
onclick="ShowDetails('resp19')"
```

Then in function `ShowDetails` write:

```
function ShowDetails(someId) {
    $('#' + someId + ' span.details_content').show();
}
```

Also as you use jQuery better to attach `click` events using `click()` method:

Html:

```
<input id="details_button" class="f_det" value="Details" type="button">
```

JS:

```
$('#details_button').click(function() {
    ShowDetails('resp19');
});
```

Note that you using `<p>` element that is for *paragraphs* and they are inline elements. Better usage will be `<div>` or other block elements.